# How to publish multiple flavour of an app as a single app on google play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

I have these product flavors

```
productFlavors {
    armv7 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 1
        }
    }
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"
        }
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 2
        }
    }
    armv7_SDK23 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 3
        }
    }
    x86_SDK23 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 4
        }
    }
    arm64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 5
        }
    }
    x64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 6
        }
    }
    arm64_SDK23 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 7
        }
    }
    x64_SDK23 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 8
        }
    }
    afat {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.standalone {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_standalone.xml'
        }
        ext {
            abiVersionCode = 9
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to generate a signed app bundle when I am trying to do that it asks which flavor you want but I want a single app that supports all architecture.

if I made some mistakes when asking the question please never mind and give me some suggestion I am in big trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are not using Product flavor in a right way , as I know product flavor is used to maintain multiple apps in single project for switch from one app to another there is build variant and while generating signed key it will defiantly ask for  which flavor you want , so if you want to config your app to run in multiple architecture than don't use product flavor try to use splits and inside splits please add your filters for example you can take help from

https://gist.github.com/ph0b/69586260bc20c58136ef   this link..............